# Skip authorization page with oAuth 2 and FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

I've successfully installed and tested the OAuth 2 workflow with Symfony 2 and FOSOAuthServerBundle.

I can request a code, and get a pair of access/refresh token successfully from a "login with" button on a third party test page i've set up and retrieve a user from my API through a custom API call. Pretty cool here.

However, each time I test the flow from the beginning, my oAuth server keeps on redirecting the user on the **authorization page**. Here are my questions.

- Once a user has authorized and app, shouldn't the authorization part of the process be skipped with OAuth 2.0 ?
- Is that fixed on the server side or should i change the way i request the credentials on client site ?
- And finally... could i debug and fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone struggles again, the solution is here :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/the_oauth_event_class.md

This feature is not default in FOSOAuthServer bundle. You have to create and `EventListener` and check client or user status, save the user's choice, and [quote:even bypass the authorization process].